# expected an array with a fixed size of x elements, found one with y elements

Tags: rust

I am attempting to change the icon (that I'm loading using the [`image` crate](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/index.html)) of an application based on the device the application is being compiled for. Unfortunately, when attempting to run the code:

```rust
    let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {
        let icon = if cfg!(target_os = "macos") {
            include_bytes!("../assets/icon-macos.png")
        } else {
            include_bytes!("../assets/icon.png")
        };
        let image = image::load_from_memory(icon)
            .expect("Failed to open icon path")
            .into_rgba8();
        let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
        let rgba = image.into_raw();
        (rgba, width, height)
    };
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
3 |           let icon = if cfg!(target_os = "macos") {
  |  ____________________-
4 | |             include_bytes!("../assets/icon-macos.png")
  | |             ------------------------------- expected because of this
5 | |         } else {
6 | |             include_bytes!("../assets/icon.png")
  | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 63249 elements, found one with 471 elements
7 | |         };
  | |_________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `include_bytes` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

While I know why this error is occurring, is there any better way to solve this issue than the code listed below?

```rust
    let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {
        if cfg!(target_os = "macos") {
            let icon = include_bytes!("../assets/icon-macos.png");
            let image = image::load_from_memory(icon)
                .expect("Failed to open icon path")
                .into_rgba8();
            let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
            let rgba = image.into_raw();
            (rgba, width, height)
        } else {
            let icon = include_bytes!("../assets/icon.png");
            let image = image::load_from_memory(icon)
                .expect("Failed to open icon path")
                .into_rgba8();
            let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
            let rgba = image.into_raw();
            (rgba, width, height)
        };
    };
```

Comment: what if you do: `let icon: &[u8] =`

Comment: You can also do `include_bytes!("xxxx").as_slice()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler infers `&[u8; <size_of_the_macos_png>]` as the type of `image` because that's what the `include_bytes!()` of the first branch resolves to, when it checks the second branch it sees `&[u8; <size_of_the_other_png>]`, but neither type can be coerced to the other so the compiler throws an error.

Fortunately you can just give the compiler a type hint to use a slice instead and it's happy to coerce to one:

```rust
    let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {
        let icon: &[u8] = if cfg!(target_os = "macos") {
            include_bytes!("../assets/icon-macos.png")
        } else {
            include_bytes!("../assets/icon.png")
        };
        let image = image::load_from_memory(icon)
            .expect("Failed to open icon path")
            .into_rgba8();
        let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
        let rgba = image.into_raw();
        (rgba, width, height)
    };
```

You could also  `as &[u8]` or `.as_slice()` either (or both) of the `include_bytes!()` invocations, but it's more verbose and sort of assymetric (or even more verbose) so I'd prefer the type hint on the binding.

Answer (score 8):

Even though `cfg`s are evaluated *before* typechecking, your code didn't compile. That's because although the compiler evaluated the `cfg!(...)` to `true` or `false`, it won't evaluate the `if` block.

To get the compiler to conditionally emit just one branch, you'll have to use `#[cfg(...)]` attributes instead:

```
let (icon_rgba, icon_width, icon_height) = {

    #[cfg!(target_os = "macos")]
    let icon = include_bytes!("../assets/icon-macos.png");
    #[cfg!(not(target_os = "macos"))]
    let icon = include_bytes!("../assets/icon.png");

    let image = image::load_from_memory(icon)
        .expect("Failed to open icon path")
        .into_rgba8();
    let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
    let rgba = image.into_raw();
    (rgba, width, height)
};
```

Comment: An advantage of this solution is that it works even if one of the PNG files is missing (e.g. because it comes with the system, or it's generated from a build script that only runs on a particular target), provided you don't try to use the missing file.

Comment: For simple conditions that's definitely the way to go, for complex ones take a look at [`cfg_if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/latest/cfg_if/).

Comment: @cafce25 Yes! I didn't know about that crate. It may deserve its own answer.